# Printar somente a primeira e última data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Uma requisição Ajax me retorna algumas informações, entre elas a `data_inicio` e `data_fim` de um mandato, porém preciso exibir somente as datas que estão em vermelho, seria:

> 23/12/1936 à 12/12/1944

[image: Como esta atualmente]

Eu preciso de uma maneira para juntar e exibir somente elas. No momento estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
var arr = [];
var per = [];

function printarPeriodo() {
 var html = '<br />';
 for (var i in per) {
     html += '<i class="fas fa-circle fa-xs"></i> &nbsp;' + per[i] + '<br />';
    }
    html += '';

    per = [];
    return html;
    }

function addArray(qual) {
    var pass = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == qual) {
         pass = true;
            }
        }
    if (!pass) {
        arr.push(qual)
    }
}
```

E utilizando ele da seguinte maneira, dentro do retorno do meu Ajax:

```
addArray(json[i].ano_inicio_f);
per.push(json[i].data_inicio_f + ' à ' + json[i].data_fim_f);
```

Comment: Essa função `addArray` é a mesma de `addToArray`?

Comment: @Sam Sim, alterei sem querer na hora de passar. Já editei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma abaixo, mas neste caso não precisa do laço `for`:

```js
var per = ['23/12/1936 a 27/12/1937', '27/12/1937 a 20/12/1940', '20/12/1940 a 22/12/1941', '22/12/1941 a 12/12/1944'];

function printarPeriodo() {
   var html = '<br />';

   // conta o tamanho da array
   var per_len = per.length;
   
   // pega a primeira data do índice [0] da array
   var data1 = per[0].split(" ").shift();
   
   // pega a segunda data do último índice da array
   var data2 = per[per_len-1].split(" ").pop();
   
   // monta a string
   var datas = data1+" a "+data2;

   html += '<i class="fas fa-circle fa-xs"></i> &nbsp;' + datas + '<br />';
   html += '';

   per = [];
   return html;
}

document.write(printarPeriodo());
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Exatamente o que eu precisava.

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de logo passar os dados da resposta em string, você pode guardá-las dentro de arrays, e essas arrays, você guarda dentro da array `per`. Dessa forma:

```
per.push([json[i].data_inicio_f, json[i].data_fim_f]);
```

E na hora de adicionar à variável `html`, você poderia fazer assim:

```
html += '<i class="fas fa-circle fa-xs"></i> &nbsp;' + per[i].join(" à ") + '<br />';
```

E para pegar o "início" e o "fim", você pode fazer:

```
var per1 = per[0];
var per2 = per[per.length - 1];
//console.log(per1[0] + " à " + per2[per2.length - 1]);
```

Ou

```
var per1 = per[0];
var per2 = per[per.length - 1];
var inicio = per1[0];
var fim = per2[per2.length - 1];
//console.log(inicio + " à " + fim);
```

Espero ter ajudado!